# Batching actions in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, batching

I read at https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch that one can use `batch` "*to ensure that multiple actions dispatched outside of React only result in a single render update*", like this (which I use in React event handler i.e.):

```
...
const submitData = event => {
    // ... some code before
    batch(() => {
        dispatch(first())
        dispatch(second())
    })
}
...
```

But my question is how to properly `batch` actions in `redux-saga` so the result is a single re-render instead of multiple, while dispatching multiple actions from a saga?
I tried to put multiple `put` in `all` array but is not sure that it actually batches `put`:

```
yield all([
    put(addFirst({first: 1})),
    put(addAnother({second: 2)),
]);
```

The above approach is because I have read documentation at https://github.com/manaflair/redux-batch where the author wrote "***Since this package got written, redux-saga improved and using all([ put(...), put(...) ]) seems to properly batch the two actions into a single subscription event, making redux-batch redundant in this scenario.***", **but** in https://github.com/manaflair/redux-batch/issues/21 another person wrote that batching is handled by `React unstable_batchedUpdates API`. Still `redux-toolkit` (which I use) have an example with `redux-batch` as a `store enhancer` (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/docs/api/configureStore.md).

So if anyone knows the correct way, please share your knowledge! Best Regards

**EDIT:**
I only use `batch` in React event handlers to batch multiple actions. In `redux-saga` I want to use `redux-batch` package.

So the correct way (if using redux-batch which apparently redux-toolkit seems to like because example) is to:

```
import { reduxBatch }                            from '@manaflair/redux-batch';
import { put, takeEvery }                        from 'redux-saga/effects';
import createSagaMiddleware                      from 'redux-saga';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';

let sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
let store = createStore(reducer, compose(reduxBatch, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware), reduxBatch));

sagaMiddleware.run(function* () {
  yield takeEvery(`*`, function* (action) {

    // Duplicate any event dispatched, and once again, store
    // listeners will only be fired after both actions have
    // been resolved/

    yield put([ action, action ]);

  });
});
```

Therefore to **yield put([ action, action ]);**, have an array in put and dispatch multiple actions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer and author of Redux Toolkit.

I actually just wrote a blog post entitled [A Comparison of Redux Batching Techniques](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/01/blogged-answers-redux-batching-techniques/),  which covers the various forms of batching available with Redux actions.

As I just commented over in that `redux-batch` issue:

> The `unstable_batchedUpdates()` usage within React-Redux itself only attempts to minimize the nested re-renders from within a single dispatch.  That does not overlap with the goal of this project, which attempts to allow dispatching multiple actions at once while only notifying store subscribers a single time.

Per your original question, I'm not sure that you can use React-Redux's `batch()` API correctly in sagas, because of the need to `yield put()`.  The `batch()` API (which is just React's own `unstable_batchedUpdates()` API, re-exported) relies on tracking any React state updates that are queued during a single event loop tick, and I suspect that use of generators may not work with that.  I'd have to see examples in action to be sure.

In any case, per the blog post, there's several options for batching, which work in different ways.  It's all a question of what actual use case you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my edit, is it correct to use yield put([ action, action ]), i.e. have array in put with multiple actions? Tnx for redux-toolkit, lifesaver for my redux project!

Comment: Yeah, while I haven't actually used `redux-batch` myself seriously, as far as I know it does allow you to pass an array of actions to `dispatch()`, and therefore should work for `put()`.

Comment: Thanks, also probably for `all([ put(...), put(...) ])`I guess

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just `put` a thunk to do that, per documentation

```
yield put((dispatch) => {
  batch(() => {
    dispatch(action1);
    dispatch(action2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to documentation?

Comment: batch is an action exported from 'react-redux', not from 'redux-saga', if that's what you are asking about

Comment: ok then it is not the same. You will see it if you read markerikson answer.